# How to use google_compute_instance_from_template?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform-template-file

This is my day 1 trying out terraform and needed some help.

I have a gcp instance template which I want to specify in my .tf and create an instance

```
resource "google_compute_instance_from_template" "tpl" {
  
  name = "k8-node-4-from-tf"
  source_instance_template = "k8-node"
  project = "myproject"
  zone = "us-west4-b"

}
```

I encountered this error when applying this

```
googleapi: Error 404: The resource 'projects/myproject/regions/us-west4/instanceTemplates/k8-node' was not found, notFound
```

The self link I see for the instance template is this,

```
 "selfLink": "projects/myproject/global/instanceTemplates/k8-node"
```

How can I resolve this error ?
Specifying a zone on .tf is mandatory.
When I try "global" for zone, this errors out :  Zone global doesn't exist

Answer (score 3):

The zone refers to  where the VM will be created, not where the template is.

So you can refer to the template as:

```
resource "google_compute_instance_from_template" "tpl" {
  
  name = "k8-node-4-from-tf"
  source_instance_template = "projects/myproject/global/instanceTemplates/k8-node"
  project = "myproject"
  zone = "us-west4-b"

}
```

or if the template is defined in your TF files:

```
resource "google_compute_instance_from_template" "tpl" {
  
  name = "k8-node-4-from-tf"
  source_instance_template = google_compute_instance_template.<your_instance_template_name>.self_link_unique
  project = "myproject"
  zone = "us-west4-b"

}
```

Everything is in the documentation so when you start with something new, it's highly recommended that you read that [first](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance_from_template#zone) since most of the time you'll find samples there.